# jQuery form not working when part of ajaxed content

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm setting up a faceted search where form data is serialized and used to determine the content to pull in using `load()`. I have two main sections, the sidebar (`.sidebar`) and the results area (`.results`), all wrapped in a wrapper (`.wrap`) div.

```
var mainContent = .results

$('#facets').change(function(e){
    mainContent.load('?' + formData + ' .results');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

When I do execute it this way, the form continues to function as intended (loads results asynchronously on change().)

...but **it's important that the form also be loaded as well**, since the facets are dynamically populated by the search results.

When I change the `mainContent` variable to the whole wrapper div...

```
var mainContent = .wrap

$('#facets').change(function(e){
    mainContent.load('?' + formData + ' .wrap');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

..the form submits on change the first time, but stops reacticting after it's pulled in to the DOM via `ajax`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**delegated event**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), as the element is loaded via ajax after DOM load:

```
$(document).on('change','#facets',function(e){
    mainContent.load('?' + formData + ' .wrap');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Mutation-Observers for such situations

```
var target = $( "#facets" )[0];
// Create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function( mutations ) {
 mutations.forEach(function( mutation ) {
 var newNodes = mutation.addedNodes; // DOM NodeList
 if( newNodes !== null ) { 
   mainContent.load('?' + formData + ' .wrap');
   e.preventDefault();
   }
  });    
 });
  var config = { 
  attributes: true, 
  childList: true, 
  characterData: true 
 };
observer.observe(target, config);
```

You can read more about [Mutation Observers](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-dom-20140710/) here.