# jQuery to show/hide dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hide/show the `ul` element when I click on the `h3` tag.  I tried some examples, maybe I am missing something.

My sample code:

```
$('#gallery').append('<h3 id="' + idx + '" >' + item.title._content + '</h3><ul style="display:none;" class="photos grp' + idx + '"></ul>');

$('h3#'+idx).click(function () {
   $(this).next('.photos.grp'+idx).toggle();
});
```

Comment: Looks like there's some missing code, a loop perhaps? Post everything so we can see how the variables are defined etc+

Comment: You need to use on('click' instead of click

Comment: Post you complete code and even better  if you make fiddle

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: sample fiddle  :http://jsfiddle.net/koushikKumar/7X67L/

Comment: Using on("click",handler) vs click(handler) makes no difference. click() is a shortcut for on("click",handler).

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery form not working when part of ajaxed content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085926/jquery-form-not-working-when-part-of-ajaxed-content)

Comment: Check my answer, You must use either `on` or `delegate` event

Answer (score 1):

> Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the
>   selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root
>   elements.

```
.delegate( selector, eventType, handler )

// jQuery 1.4.3+
$( elements ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );
// jQuery 1.7+
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

You can use jQuery delegate events handler which can be used on your dynamic added elements.

e.g. In your case

```
$('#gallery').append('<h3 id="' + idx + '" >' + item.title._content + '</h3><ul style="display:none;" class="photos grp' + idx + '"></ul>');

$('h3#'+idx).on('click', function() {
   $(this).next('.photos.grp'+idx).toggle();
});
```

**OR**

```
$('h3#'+idx).delegate('#gallery', 'click', function() {
   $(this).next('.photos.grp'+idx).toggle();
});
```

Here, *#gallery* is your Parent element of all child elements.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are dynamically You should use this

```
var id = 'h3#'+idx;
$('#gallery').on('click',id,function(){
    $(this).next('.photos.grp'+idx).toggle();
})
```

Comment: in html add <div id="gallery"></div> http://jsbin.com/xerojane/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('h3#'+idx).on('click',function () {
       $(this).next('.photos.grp'+idx).toggle();
  });

Because you are appending html from jquery then use `.on()` shown above.
```

Comment: maybe i'v something miss in my explanation, please look my code on jsbin, i'v try use on, trigger and a lot of other stuff..