# jQuery onPropagation not working with .getJSON()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a table. When I click on a cell, it creates rows below it that show the next-level-down detail, using a .click() event listener for that class. It does this with a .getJSON() call, that I then use to populate the rows that follow. I added the following `.newtable` class to each new (sub-detail) row. At the bottom of my page I have the following, so if you click anywhere on the page it closes these sub-detail rows:

```
$('html').click(function(){
    $('.newtable').remove();        
});
```

However, I don't want it to close the sub-detail if the user clicks in one of the newly opened cells, so I tried both of the following with no avail... is it b/c the rows are being added after the page loads or something?

```
$('.newtable td').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("table .newtable").on("click","td",function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Attach the listener to an element which is always present on the page, although I would argue that using `stopPropagation()` is more-often-than-not an anti-pattern.

Comment: So would adding `onClick="javascript: $(this).stopPropagation();"` to each of the cells newly created by the `.getJSON()` call work? I hate to add that much inline code :)

Comment: you need event delegation for the event to work:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085926/jquery-form-not-working-when-part-of-ajaxed-content

Comment: @EhsanSajjad thanks for the advice. I will incorporate that in the future, though the answer I accepted worked for this go-around.

Comment: @MeanDean73 I don't believe I have ever recommended inline JS at any point in my career; that's certainly not what I'm recommending here. My point is that if you are writing good code, you shouldn't ever have to use `stopPropagation`. (Exceptions obviously exist; I don't think this is one.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work for you without the other two code snippets you're trying.

```
$('html').click(function(event){
    if($(event.target).hasClass('newtable') || $(event.target).parents('tr').first().hasClass('newtable')){
        return;
    } else {
        $('.newtable').remove();        
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried it, but it's not working. I think it is because the created rows have the class `.newtable`, not the individual cells in that row.

Comment: @MeanDean73 yeah, sorry I was being 'dof' as we say in SA!  Was working on `this` which is ofcourse the `html` element, I knew there was a reason I added the `event` argument to the function!

Comment: got it! Changed it to `.hasClass('newtable')` instead of `.hasClass('.newtable')` and it worked! Thanks so much!!

Comment: @MeanDean73, yes, apologies, glad you got it figured!