# Loading Json content through ajax does not open popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, twitter-bootstrap

jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function()
     {
        $('.img-responsive').on("click",function(){
          $('.modal-body').html( $(this).parent().html() );
            $('#myModal').modal({show:true})
        });
     })
    </script>
```

Load content dynamically from json file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function showcontent(contentId)
   {
        var image=industry_contents[contentId-1].image_path.length;
        var imagehtml="";
        for(var i=0;i<image;i++)
        {
            if(i==0)
            {
                imagehtml+='<div  class="item active">';
                imagehtml+='<img src="'+industry_contents[contentId-1].image_path[i]+'" class="img-responsive">';
                imagehtml+='</div>';

            }
            else
            {
                imagehtml+='<div  class="item">';
                imagehtml+='<img src="'+industry_contents[contentId-1].image_path[i]+'" class="img-responsive">'; 
                imagehtml+='</div>';
            }

        }
        $('#chartimage').html(imagehtml);

   }
 </script>
```

link for slider and modal popup :

```
`http://www.bootply.com/byUX0u7K0s`
```

In the above code i have a mini slider with prev and next button in bootstrap in which i am trying to open a popup modal of each image.
so when we load the content by default everthing works fine(popup opens).But when i load the content dynamically using jSon And ajax the popup is not working.is there any wrong in my jQuery code?? any help would be appreciated...

Comment: there is no `#chartimage` item in your html in bootply, so we only have to guess where you put that content, I suspect you should be putting it into `.carousel-inner`. BTW I also don't see ajax or json in your showcontent function...

Comment: add click event code just after apepending or use event delegation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085926/jquery-form-not-working-when-part-of-ajaxed-content/25085987#25085987

Comment: @EhsanSajjad what should i use in the place of #facets??in my code...

Comment: you have to put your selector: ``.img-responsive``

Comment: @EhsanSajjad <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).on('change','.img-responsive',function(e){
 {
   $('.modal-body').html( $(this).parent().html() );
  $('#myModal').modal({show:true})

 })
</script>   this is not working at all...can you please just update it if any???

Comment: you need click instead of change, your event is of click

Comment: @EhsanSajjad mashallah bro its working fine...you made my day!!

Comment: @SalmanAmaan glad it helped, you can upvote my answer whose link i posted in comments that helped..:)