# JQuery click event doesn't work after first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, paging

I want to create a custom paging for my mvc project. Here is my next button. It works at when I click to it first but after that it doesn't work. Where is my mistake?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnNext").click(function () {
              $.ajax({
                    url: '/Customer/Next',
                    data: { currentPageIndex: document.getElementById('currentPageIndex').value },
                    success: function (response) {
                        $("body").html(response);
                    }
                });
            });
       });
      </script>
```

Comment: there is brackets problem there is missing '});' brackets in the end

Comment: It looks like your replacing the whole `<body>` so the original button with `id=btnNext` no longer exists. If the new html also has a button with `id=btnNext`, then use event delegation with `.on`

Comment: @Kartikeya it because of copy and paste to here but thanks.

Comment: you need delegated event as html is updated after DOM load:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085926/jquery-form-not-working-when-part-of-ajaxed-content/25085987#25085987 , instead of `change` write `click` and pass your selector in the second parameter

Comment: Replace : ``$("#btnNext").click(function () {`` with ``$(document).on("click","#btnNext",function () {``

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$("body").on('click', '#btnNext', function () {
```

instead of

```
$("#btnNext").click(function () {
```

Take a look to know more about the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event handler.